# A question related to function enclosure and call-by-name of Python language

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, nested-function

Consider the following code snippet:

```py
def part1():
    flist = []
    for i in range(10):
        def hello():
            print(f"Hello {i = }.")
        flist.append(hello)
    
    for f in flist:
        f()
part1()
```

Its output is:

```
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
Hello i = 9.
```

instead of from 0 to 9.

When modify the code like this:

```py
def part2():
    flist = []
    for i in range(10):
        v = i
        def hello():
            print(f"Hello {v = }.")
        flist.append(hello)
        
    
    for f in flist:
        f()
part2()
```

The output is not change.

But when modify the code like this:

```py
def part3():
    flist = []
    for i in range(10):
        v = i
        def hello():
            print(f"Hello {v = }.")
        flist.append(hello)
        del v
        
    
    for f in flist:
        f()
part3()
```

An error raised:

```
NameError: cannot access free variable 'v' where it is not associated with a value in enclosing scope
```

Why this is going to happen? Can anyone give me an explanation in low-level view?

And if I want the program to print from 0 to 9. Without change the pattern (still use nested function approach like this) What modification should I make to achieve my goal?

Comment: Note, Python is not call by name, in any case, that isn't relevant here, since call by name refers to an evaluation strategy, which is basically about the semantics of how functions treat arguments. What you are seeing here is the result of scope. Python has lexical, late-binding scope. But you pobably already understand this! Consider a simple function, `def foo(): print(x)` OK, now I do `foo()` and what happens? I get a `NameError`. There is no name bound to `x` in that scope. But I can then do `x = 1; foo()` and you get `1`, and then `x = 2; foo()` and you get `2`.

Comment: That's basically what's going on in your loop. Your functions all refer to the variable `i` (or `v`) in the enclosing scope, and the value of that variable **when you call it** is the last value from the loop, i.e. `9`

Comment: The principled way to fix this is to use a function factory, to create an intermediate variable that doesn't change, so: `def hello_maker(x): def hello(): print(x) ... return hello` (if you follow without indentation...). Then simply `flist.append(make_hello(i))`